# CSS files in the same folder as HTML files work differently than if they were in separate folders. [Github Pages]

Tags: html, css, directory, github-pages, subdirectory

I am trying to host a website on GitHub Pages which seems to **only work if I place the HTML, CSS and JS files in the root folder**. But the problem with this is that the positioning of elements on a page of my website is messed up.

*Folder structure where files are together with faulty result*:

[image]

[image]

```
HTML: <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
```

*Folder structure where files are separated with correct result:*

[image]

[image]

```
HTML: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/home.css">
```

Will anyone explain why this problem occurs?